# Prove RSA scheme is insecure

Tags: encryption, rsa, provable-security

Im reviewing my crypto and I would like to prove the following: RSA experiment where the adversary is given N, e, and y. The adversary knows p, q.

I know the RSA scheme is built on the idea that it is hard to find 2 large primes that are factors of N, and we already have this so it's easy to solve for d now. In order to prove this we need to solve for d which is the secret because [$c^d$ mod N] is the decryption of a cypher text. I just don't know how to formalize this into an adversary and show the steps to solve for d which would give A a success prob of 1.

also d is equivalent to

d = [e^{-1} mod ()]

We know everything in that equation except for (). Is the equation for ()=(−1,−1)? I'm almost sure this is the correct equation, and if it is then we can use it to solve for d and the question is solved.

Comment: HINT: This is the same calculation that needs to be done when generating a private key for a legitimate user.

Comment: Is this homework? It seems like one. Could you indicate?

Comment: @kelalaka this user has posted nothing but homework questions for the past few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

The security of the RSA cryptosystem requires that p,q are secret. If an adversary knows prime pair $(p,q)$, it can compute $\lambda(n)$ as follows:

> $\lambda(n)=lcm(p-1,q-1)$.

For a properly chosen public key part $e$, the private key, $d$, is then computed as follows:

> $d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod{\lambda(n)}$

Thus, an attacker who knows $(p,q)$ can recover the private key from the public key.

Comment: More precisely, an attacker who knows $(p,q)$ can recover a valid decryption exponent from the public key, and decipher. The decryption exponent is not unique: $d'=(e^{-1} \bmod \lambda(n))+\lambda(n)$ works too.

Comment: Well, we don't answer HW questions but rather hint [at the comments](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1115/18298)